Podman is logging me out from my graphical session
I am starting with containers and want to set up testing environment for my LAMP app.
The setup
I create a pod, so that apache and database containers can be bound together.
podman pod create --name tlamp -p 8000:80
--userns=keep-id:uid=33,gid=33

I need the keep-id mapping so that my project that will be mounted into a container will be accessible by www-data user.
podman run -d --pod tlamp --name=tapache --replace --volume ./projekt/t/:/var/www/html/:Z docker.io/library/php:8.1.3-apache

The error
At this point my session crashes and I am prompted to log in. Following is an excerpt from my journal:
Nov 12 18:57:20 KuBook conmon[673347]: conmon 78b223406fdae966e159 <nwarn>: Failed to open cgroups file:>
Nov 12 18:57:21 KuBook uwsm_sway[1908055]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Broken pipe
Nov 12 18:57:21 KuBook uwsm_sway[1908187]: Io error: Broken pipe (os error 32)
Nov 12 18:57:21 KuBook uwsm_sway[1908187]: Io error: Broken pipe (os error 32)
Nov 12 18:57:21 KuBook uwsm_sway[1908187]: Io error: Broken pipe (os error 32)
Nov 12 18:57:21 KuBook uwsm_sway[1908187]: Error: ExitFailure(1)
Nov 12 18:57:21 KuBook polkitd[966]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:28 (system bus n>

My system
Is not left as it was out of the box. I use an openSuse distribution, which has a Sway wayland compositor running as systemd unit.
Following is the process tree. Last three lines show my terminal emulator.
          1 ?        Ss     0:08 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize=54
    583 ?        Ss     0:03 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
    611 ?        Ss     0:01 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
    786 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/haveged -w 1024 -v 0 -F
    846 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent --watch --plymouth
    915 ?        S<sl   0:00 /sbin/auditd
    937 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --scope system --audit
    939 ?        S      0:16  \_ dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 9 --machine-id 387ec4c9f7a84c1187de334b
    941 ?        Ss     0:04 avahi-daemon: running [KuBook.local]
    942 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
    944 ?        Ssl    0:01 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
    959 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/ofonod -n
    966 ?        Ssl    0:09 /usr/libexec/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
    971 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/smartd -n -q never
    974 ?        Ssl    2:06 /usr/sbin/nscd
    990 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-machined
   1041 ?        Ss     0:04 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
   1042 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/mcelog --ignorenodev --daemon --foreground
   1094 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/ModemManager
   1096 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
   1108 ?        Ssl    0:07 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
   1189 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
   1190 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/syncthing serve --no-browser --no-restart --logflags=0
   1225 ?        SNl    0:40  \_ /usr/bin/syncthing serve --no-browser --no-restart --logflags=0
   1192 ?        Ss     0:01 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -u -t -f
   1232 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/chronyd
   1282 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/libexec/mbim-proxy
   1354 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/postfix/bin//master -w
   1356 ?        S      0:00  \_ qmgr -l -t fifo -u
1099957 ?        S      0:00  \_ pickup -l -t fifo -u
   1376 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -n
   1400 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
   1419 ?        SLs    0:00 greetd
 900502 tty1     SLs+   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/greetd --session-worker 12
 900917 tty1     S+     0:00      \_ systemctl --user start --wait wayland-wm@sway.service
 900985 tty1     S+     0:00          \_ waitpid -e 901085
   1937 ?        Ssl    0:13 /usr/libexec/upower/upowerd
   2008 ?        SNsl   0:00 /usr/libexec/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
   2211 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/libexec/power-profiles-daemon
   9080 ?        Ssl    0:03 /usr/libexec/udisks2/udisksd
  12563 ?        Ssl    2:19 /usr/bin/rustdesk --service
 904744 ?        S      0:00  \_ sudo -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 -u jakubo /usr/lib/rustdesk/rustd
 904749 ?        Sl     0:11      \_ /usr/lib/rustdesk/rustdesk --server
 904759 ?        S      0:00          \_ sudo -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 -u jakubo /usr/lib/rustde
 904773 ?        Sl     0:00              \_ /usr/lib/rustdesk/rustdesk --tray
1906936 ?        Ss     0:01 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
1906938 ?        S      0:00  \_ (sd-pam)
1907028 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket
1907051 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --scope user
1907063 ?        S      0:00  |   \_ dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 10 --machine-id 387ec4c9f7a84c1187d
1907585 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/dconf-service
1907741 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/at-spi2/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
1907848 ?        S<sl   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
1908037 ?        Sl     0:00  |   \_ /usr/libexec/pulse/gsettings-helper
1908078 ?        S<sl   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/pipewire
1908079 ?        S<sl   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/wireplumber
1910153 ?        S      0:00  \_ catatonit -P
 679316 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/at-spi2/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
 900952 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ /usr/bin/waitpid -e 900917
 901085 ?        Ssl    0:37  \_ sway
 901122 ?        Z      0:00  |   \_ [systemd-notify] <defunct>
 901174 ?        S      0:00  \_ swaybg -o eDP-1 -i /usr/share/backgrounds/sway/Sway_Wallpaper_Blue_1920x
 901185 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
 901268 ?        Sl     0:01  \_ swaybar -b bar-0
 901322 ?        S      0:00  |   \_ /bin/bash /home/jakubo/.config/sway/swaybar.bash
 901323 ?        S      0:00  |       \_ /bin/bash /home/jakubo/.config/sway/swaybar.bash
1552234 ?        S      0:00  |       |   \_ sleep 1
 901324 ?        S      0:00  |       \_ swaymsg -t subscribe -m ["window","tick","input"]
 901325 ?        S      0:00  |       \_ /bin/bash /home/jakubo/.config/sway/swaybar.bash
 901270 ?        S      0:00  \_ swayidle -w timeout 300 swaymsg "output * dpms off" resume swaymsg "outp
 901272 ?        S      0:00  \_ swayidle -w timeout 900 swaylock --config /etc/swaylock/openSUSEway.conf
 901298 ?        S      0:00  \_ sh -c tail -f $SWAYSOCK.wob | wob --config /etc/sway/wob/wob.ini
 901304 ?        S      0:00  |   \_ tail -f /run/user/1000/sway-ipc.1000.901085.sock.wob
 901305 ?        S      0:00  |   \_ wob --config /etc/sway/wob/wob.ini
 901306 ?        Sl     0:00  \_ swaync --style /etc/sway/swaync/style.css --config /etc/sway/swaync/conf
 901308 ?        Sl     0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
 901330 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/at-spi2/at-spi-bus-launcher
 901357 ?        S      0:00  |   \_ /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi
 901369 ?        S      0:00  |       \_ dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 9 --machine-id 387ec4c9f7a84c11
 901371 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/gvfs/gvfsd
 901399 ?        Sl     0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f
 901431 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/at-spi2/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
 901461 ?        Ssl    0:03  \_ /usr/bin/telegram-desktop -workdir /home/jakubo/.local/share/TelegramDes
 901472 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/agent
 901475 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
 901495 ?        Sl     0:00  \_ Xwayland :0 -rootless -core -terminate 10 -listenfd 31 -listenfd 33 -dis
 901605 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
 901646 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
 901664 ?        Ss     0:00  |   \_ fusermount3 -o rw,nosuid,nodev,fsname=portal,auto_unmount,subtype=po
 901691 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
 901725 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-wlr
 902899 ?        Sl     4:02  \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
 903142 ?        Sl     0:00  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID 2024101120564
 903208 ?        Sl     0:10  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 4332
 903254 ?        Sl     0:03  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 4341
 903441 ?        Sl     0:01  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 3324
 903464 ?        Sl     0:05  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 3324
 904022 ?        Sl     0:00  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID 2024101120564
 904034 ?        Sl     0:05  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 3915
 904094 ?        Sl     0:28  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 3915
 904809 ?        Sl     0:10  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 3915
1046475 ?        Sl     1:29  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 3915
1309409 ?        Sl     0:00  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 3921
1318509 ?        Sl     0:00  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 3921
1495037 ?        Sl     0:00  |   \_ /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -isForBrowser -prefsLen 3953
1051779 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ gpg-agent --homedir /home/jakubo/.gnupg --daemon
1051791 ?        SLl    0:00  |   \_ scdaemon --multi-server
1166612 ?        Sl     0:03  \_ alacritty --config-file /etc/alacritty/alacritty.toml
1166676 pts/0    Ss     0:00      \_ /bin/bash
1552393 pts/0    R+     0:00          \_ ps axf


Can you please point me into the right direction? I have already tried altering my containers.conf, but with no success
[engine]
cgroup_manager = "cgroupfs"
events_logger = "file"
cgroup_conf = [
    "memory.use_hierarchy=1",
    "memory.max=max",
    "cgroup.procs=0"
]
unified_cgroup_hierarchy = true


just out of an abundance of caution: you're not running your graphical session as www-data user, right?

No, the www-data (33) is used by apache in the container. On the host machine I have an id 1000. I need ownership of web root mapped to be of 33 in container.
This is actually not yet tested - but before, I was trying to start my container alone, not in the pod, and the --userns option was set directly on podman run...
However then I didn't have this problem of being logged out.

yeah, somehow your wayland crashes – I guess it's the compositor – for some reason. I'm just stumbling in the dark there, just as you.
